# Non continuous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I'm struggling to answer this question :
Show that this function admits partial derivatives in every direction without being continuous in $(0,0)$:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 y^2\log \left|x\right|& \text{ if } x \neq 0 
\\
 0 &  \text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$

I have no problem showing that f admits partial derivatives in every directions, but I'm struggling to show that it is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** What is $f\left( \frac{1}{n}, e^{-n^2}\right)$ ? What *should b*e the limit of this sequence if $f$ was continuous ?

Comment: I mean we have got : $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(\frac{1}{n},e^{-\frac{1}{n^2}})=(0,1)$, so it is not really useful to get the continuity in $(0,0)$?

Comment: @MartinJessenne typo, corrected !

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Given a constant $c$, can you find a curve along which $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ and $f(x,y) \equiv c$?